# Python - finding things in an opened python file

Tags: python

If I opened a python file using "open" and then tried to search for something specific, like a parameter passed into a function, assuming that the python file is in the proper format with proper spacings, how will I go about finding what all the parameters passed into functions are?

Comment: You might find this question of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163307/is-there-tools-for-python-source-code-analysis

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tokenizer` standard Python module, see http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/tokenize.html